# Creating an Apache Netbeans macro in VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, netbeans, key-bindings

I am trying to create a keyboard shortcut for VS Code that allows me to "paste" the line `System.out.println();` and then leave my cursor in between the braces. I am used to using Netbeans, where you can type "sout" + "tab" and the line will be pasted. Is there a way to do this in VS Code using the the `keybindings.json` file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add extra keybindings to achieve this. Actually when you type `syso`, there will be intellisense provided by **Java Language Server** that print standard out, then press **Tab** you will get code. Like the gif shows:

[image]